# query mongoose to find all by a name and then picking the last created

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

What I'm trying to accomplish is to first sort out all documents not containing the correct string, and then picking the document that was last created by those.

My query now looks like this :

```
 projectModel.findOne().sort({owner: req.body.owner, date: -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
```

but it gives me errors obviously.
How to do this correctly?

***I'm very grateful for every answer!***

Comment: Dont u think.. u r doing wrong while passing `owner : req.body.owner` in sort query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this 
You are trying to find owner in sort which will not work because sort function will take only one argument if you are using date as sort parameter.
So you can do one thing just put the owner parameter in findone function and then everything will work fine as required.

`projectModel.findOne({owner: req.body.owner}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, doc) { // your codes here }`

Comment: Can you please mark this as expected answer @Charlie

Answer (score 0):

please try add this pamater **_id:-1** and **limit:1** in your sort chain

`projectModel.findOne().sort({owner: req.body.owner, _id: -1}).limit(1)`

Comment: oops sorry my bad

Comment: db.users.findOne({username:"umutyerebakmaz"}).sort({_id:-1})..... your mongoose  chain.